# Excel - autofill formula horizontally with cell number increment

Tags: excel, autofill, array-formulas

I have the following problem. I want to copy this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(--($C3:$Q3=C4:Q4))` ,which is in cell C13, to the adjacent cells (D13, E13, F13 etc.), but I want $C3:$Q3 to become $C4:$Q4. (basically `=SUMPRODUCT(--($C3:$Q3=C4:Q4))` ====> `=SUMPRODUCT(--($C4:$Q4=C4:Q4))` and so on). Dragging horizontally doesn't help, since autofill increments the rows and not the column number.

I tried with OFFSET, but as far as I understand, it references the data and not the formulas. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `C13` put

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(OFFSET($C$3:$Q$3,SUM(COLUMN(C13)-COLUMN($C$13)),,,)=$C$4:$Q$4))
```

Then drag this across columns.

Note:

1) This assumes `$C$4:$Q$4` is a fixed range to compare against as it remains the same in your given example

2) That you don't mind the fact that the formula in column D will self reference for comparison

You could also just enclose in `Index` instead.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX(OFFSET($C$3:$Q$3,COLUMN(C13)-COLUMN($C$13),,,),0,0)=$C$4:$Q$4))
```

Example:

[image: Example]

**Edit:**

Based on share workbook where need to drag across columns and down rows to compare 64 * 64 matrix element wise (where each element is a row in the source array)

In C71 put the following and drag down and across to BM133:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX($C$2:$W$64,MATCH($B71,$B$2:$B$64,0),0)=INDEX($C$2:$W$64,MATCH(C$70,$B$2:$B$64,0),0)))
```

Result:

[image: Sample from results]

With column R test on gender being different added in C71 put the following and drag down and across to BM133:

```
=IF(INDEX($C$2:$W$64,MATCH($B71,$B$2:$B$64,0),16)<>INDEX($C$2:$W$64,MATCH(C$70,$B$2:$B$64,0),16),SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX($C$2:$W$64,MATCH($B71,$B$2:$B$64,0),0)=INDEX($C$2:$W$64,MATCH(C$70,$B$2:$B$64,0),0))),"")
```

Comment: For some reason your formula displays an error message on my version of excel. I edited it to look like this:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDEX(OFFSET($C$3:$Q$3;COLUMN(C13)-COLUMN($C$13);0);0;0)=$C$4:$Q$4))

The only issue i have now is that i can't drag the new formula down and fill it in. 
For example I can drag the old formula (the one in my question) down from C13 do C20, but I can't drag the new formula from D13 to C20.

Comment: It doesn't display the error now, but i still can't drag the new formula down. I mean I can, but it gives me wrong results.

Comment: Yes, I get it, but the idea is to transfer all the formulas from column C to column D. With your formula I can transfer only the first (C13 acrross), but I cant transfer the rest (C14 across).

Comment: Yes, I do, but the data isn't in english.

Comment: Here's the excel spreadsheet: https://ufile.io/oytxm
I guess I'll have to give you some context then. The numbers from 1 to 64 are people. The first table is the data. I have to check how many of the answers of person 1 are equal to person 2 (wit person 3, 4 etc.), so I made the table below the data for that reason.

Comment: A2 throw W64 is data only. The table below is meant to pull data and calculate number of matching responses. So, yes. Person 1 has to have 20 matching responses with person 1 (with himself...).

Comment: You have  to compare the range of answers of person 1 (C2:W2) with the answers of person 2 (C3:W3). Then person 1 (C2:W2) with person 3(C4:W4) and so on.

Comment: Yes, I think that's it! Just one last question. If i want to count only  the questions of the opposite sex where should i put the If function? (The sex is in the R column)

Comment: Update for gender https://ufile.io/8uixw  Please let me know if that works or if I need to update further.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Pleasure. Glad we got there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Converting the formulas to text should work.

1. Copy your `=SUMPRODUCT` formula down as many rows as you need columns filled.
2. Convert the formulas to text.  Highlight the rows you copied down and find and replace all `=` with `'=`
3. Copy those rows.
4. Select the cell in the column where you want the formulas and paste special with `values` and `transpose` selected.
5. Highlight the pasted cells and find and replace all `=` with `=`

Unfortunately the last step is necessary to make it work even though it seems redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Andrew. The only issue is that your method doesn't edit the anchored numbers.